# How to check if a jquery element is an `del` tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an HTML checkbox next to a paragraph. When the user check the box, I want to put a strike through the paragraph using [css bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/).

To add the strike through, I should wrap the paragraph with `<del></del>` tag.

I am able to wrap the paragraph correctly with the `<del></del>` when the box is checked. However, I am unable to remove the `<del></del>` tag when the user uncheck the box.

My code seems to be failing to check if the element is a `del`.

I created a fiddler to show you what is happening https://jsfiddle.net/vo1npqdx/1335/

in the fiddler, you will see that the code `if (display.is('del')) { .... }` is failing so the code inside the if statement never gets fired.

I tried to print the html code to the console to make sure I am dealing with the correct element, and it is clearly showing the correct code.

How can I unwrap my paragraph from the `del` tag?

Here is my JS code

```
$(function(){

  $('.custom_delete_file:checkbox').click(function(e){
    var self = $(this);
    var display = self.closest('.input-width-input').find('.custom_delete_file_name > p');

    if (self.is(':checked')) {
      display.wrapInner('<del></del>');
    } else {

      var firstDisplay = display.parent().children().first();
      console.log(firstDisplay.html())
      if (display.is('del')) { // this is failing
        firstDisplay.unwrap();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Here is my HTML code

```js
$(function(){

  $('.custom_delete_file:checkbox').click(function(e){
    var self = $(this);
    var display = self.closest('.input-width-input').find('.custom_delete_file_name > p');

    if (self.is(':checked')) {
      display.wrapInner('<del></del>');
    } else {

      var firstDisplay = display.parent().children().first();
      console.log(firstDisplay.html())
      if (display.is('del')) { // this is failing
        firstDisplay.unwrap();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
        body {
            padding-top: 65px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }

        /* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
        .body-content {
            padding-left: 15px;
            padding-right: 15px;
        }

        /* Override the default bootstrap behavior where horizontal description lists
           will truncate terms that are too long to fit in the left column.
           Also, add a 8pm to the bottom margin
        */
        .dl-horizontal dt {
            white-space: normal;
            margin-bottom: 8px;
        }

        /* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
        input,
        select,
        textarea,
        .input-width-input {
            max-width: 380px;
        }

        .uploaded-file-name {
            max-width: 310px;
        }

        .help-block-standard {
            display: block;
            margin-top: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            color: #737373;
        }

        /* Vertically align the table cells inside body-panel */
        .panel-body .table > tr > td
        {
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        .panel-body-with-table
        {
            padding: 0;
        }

        .mt-5 {
            margin-top: 5px !important;
        }

        .mb-5 {
            margin-bottom: 5px !important;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="http://laravel54.dev/assets/asset/6" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="UA428wC4vxZgb9OmNCGBIkosCN4KuS49VgFiUTET">
            <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
            <div class="form-group ">
    <label for="name" class="col-md-2 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" id="name" value="Some new test" minlength="1" maxlength="255" required="true" placeholder="Enter name here...">
        
    </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group ">
    <label for="notes" class="col-md-2 control-label">Notes</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="notes" cols="50" rows="10" id="notes" maxlength="1000"></textarea>
        
    </div>
</div>



<div class="form-group " style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <label for="picture" class="col-md-2 control-label">Picture</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="input-group uploaded-file-group">
            <label class="input-group-btn">
                <span class="btn btn-default">
                    Browse <input type="file" name="picture" id="picture" class="hidden">
                </span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control uploaded-file-name" readonly>
        </div>

            <div class="input-group input-width-input">

                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="custom_delete_picture" class="custom_delete_file"> Delete
                </span>

                <span class="input-group-addon custom_delete_file_name">
                    <p>uploads/zCmPgC5yMor77DaM50nTTnSnxh4y75e7B06WUFFM.jpeg</p>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
    </div>
</div>



                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Update">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
var del = display.children().first();

console.log(del)

if (del.is('del')) {
    del.contents().unwrap();
}
```

The `del` is element should be the first child of `display`. I've used `console.log(del)` because using `html()` is effectively giving you the `innerHTML`, which isn't particular helpful.

In your original code, `display` is your `p` element and this line was just going 'up one, down one', ending up back at the `p`:

```
var firstDisplay = display.parent().children().first();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution to your answer.

```
$(function(){

  $('.custom_delete_file:checkbox').click(function(e){
    var self = $(this);
    var display = self.closest('.input-width-input').find('.custom_delete_file_name > p');

    if (self.is(':checked')) {
      display.wrapInner('<del></del>');
    } else {

      $(".custom_delete_file_name:eq(0) p").html($(".custom_delete_file_name:eq(0) p del").html());     
    }
  });
});
```

But keep in mind you don't have to wrap it with a tag to make it strike through. You can simply add a css class or a style property with

```
text-decoration: line-through;
```

and toggle it.
This is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach... Intead of unwrap, just overwrite the p again with the content inside of del...

```
$('.custom_delete_file:checkbox').click(function(e){
    var self = $(this);
    var display = self.closest('.input-width-input').find('.custom_delete_file_name > p');

    if (self.is(':checked')) {
        display.wrapInner('<del></del>');
    }
    else {
        display.html(display.find('del').text());
    }
});
```

I hope it helps